# Magento enterprise edition indexing

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, indexing, enterprise-1.13

Does magento enterprise edition needs cron to be set in order to run Indexing the following process.

1. URL Redirects
2. Stock Status
3. Catalog Search Index
4. Product URL Rewrites
5. Category URL Rewrites
6. Catalog Category/Product Index
7. Catalog product price

I have flat catalog for category enabled, but whenever I modify category attributes like meta data, the changes are not getting reflected in the front end. But whenever I disable flat catalog for category, the changes are reflected. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

As you thought it is not displaying because you haven't re-indexed.

A cron would be one option for this if you can't do it manually afterwards. This could be ran from the command line in the shell directory - php indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: A cron has to be set up? because I can not see checkboxes against these indexes?

Comment: updated answer on how to run them but yes a cron or manually through the CL

Comment: I am asking that it must be run to to reflect the changes

Comment: yes it must be ran to reflect the changes, like i said - 
As you thought it is not displaying because you haven't re-indexed.

Comment: But indexes says 'Ready' state?

Comment: that doesn't matter in this case